# Cannot install python packages using pip on Ubuntu 16.04 using wired LAN connection

Tags: python, pip, installation, lan

I seem to be the only one facing this problem, all others don't have a problem installing the packages even using our wired LAN connection, pip works well when I use a wireless wifi.
Is there any configuration I need to change ?
I didn't find any solution to this question, I'll provide with any other detail that could be of help.

Comment: It's a problem with your computer / network. Nothing that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If someone could help me with the settings to be changed it would be really nice.

Comment: You haven’t provided any information about the problem itself.

Comment: To make it clearer: No, we don't fix computers here. Try [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Okay I did post it at superuser